# Prove that $\left | \cos x - \cos y \right | \leq \left | x - y \right |, \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}.$

Tags: real-analysis

This is one of the problem in my text book where the section which the problem is stated talks about the mean value theorem and Rolle's theorem. By looking at this, I have no idea where to start. Can I have some hints??

Comment: The derivative of $\cos t$ has absolute value $\le 1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\cos(x)$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$.

By Mean value theorem $|\cos(x) - \cos(y)| = |sin(\xi)||x - y|$ where $\xi \in (x,y)$ or $(y,x)$.

$|\sin(x)| < 1$ $\forall$ $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now get your answer.

Answer (score 6):

This follows also from the standard $|\sin(x)| \leq |x|$:

$$\left| cos(x) - \cos(y)  \right|=2  \left| \sin(\frac{x+y}{2}) \sin(\frac{y-x}{2})  \right| \leq 2 \cdot  1 \cdot \left|\frac{y-x}{2}  \right|$$

Comment: This is more fundamental and simpler than the other techniques involving differentiation and integration. Differentiation/integration of trig functions are ultimately dependent on $\sin x < x < \tan x$ inequality for $x \in (0, \pi / 2)$. (+1)

Comment: On the other hand, $\sin x < x < \tan x$ is a geometric fact, just as the proof for $\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\sin(y)$. Maybe you'd argue you can use complex exponentials, but then you really need complex analysis--i.e. calculus.

Answer (score 4):

By integration:
$$|\cos y - \cos x| = \left|-\int_x^y \sin t dt \right| \leq \int_x^y |\sin t dt| \leq \int_x^y 1 dt = |y-x|$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
By ${\it Mean Value Theorem}$,
$\exists\ \xi \in {\mathbb R}\quad \ni\quad \min\braces{x,y} < \xi < \max\braces{x,y}$ which satisfies
$$
{\cos\pars{x} - \cos\pars{y} \over x - y}  = -\sin\pars{\xi}
\quad\imp\quad 
\verts{\cos\pars{x} - \cos\pars{y} \over x - y}  = \verts{\sin\pars{\xi}} \leq 1
$$